# Terraform Lambda function configuration changes

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, terraform

I want to create a lambda function with terraform. But the standard timeout for a lambda function is set at 3 sec and my function takes longer then this to execute.
[image]
I know you can just change the configuration for this but my question is how and if you can do this in terraform. My current file to create the lambda function looks like this.

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "etl_pipeline_test" {
  function_name = var.project_name
  image_uri = "${var.ecr_repo_uri}:${var.image_tag}"
  package_type = "Image"
  role = var.execution_role_arn
}
```

I fairly new to terraform and AWS but could it also be possible that you define this timeout in a policy of some sort, I looked but did not find anything so my best guess is still at terraform.
All help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`aws_lambda_function` has a [timeout](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/lambda_function#timeout) argument:

```
resource "aws_lambda_function" "etl_pipeline_test" {
  function_name = var.project_name
  image_uri = "${var.ecr_repo_uri}:${var.image_tag}"
  package_type = "Image"
  role = var.execution_role_arn

  timeout = 60
}
```

Comment: Damn I completely looked over this in the documentation. Thanks a lot!